# Is it possible to include a cucumber-jvm step definition from a "framework" location?

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

Is it possible to define a step class in a common location to be used by different modules? The problem is that you can't put a `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on the class because you don't know with which context it will be used.

I tried to wire in this step class from the `cucumber.xml` included by other step classes, but it seems that this was ignored.